# How to get IAM Credentials from Cognito Username/Password from CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I want to be able to get IAM Credentials from an IdentityPool via Cognito user/pass authentication from the command line.

I can't find anything in the aws-cli that does this in one-step ( or even in a number of steps such that it could be used in a bash script)?
Does anyone know about any cli tools that do it?

I am trying to write a quick script to get IAM Credentials to plugin to Postman for testing an API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are thinking in reverse! IAM is for setting the users to use the AWS' services. Cognito is for user authentication to your apps, apis.

For example, if I have a pool, `test-pool`, I create an IAM user and give it an access to the `test-pool`; then I will use the `access` and `secret` keys, of the IAM user, within the application with the Cognito pool properties (`id`, `region`) to contact the user pool for authentication purposes.

Therefore, if you have 100 users to your one app, then you have one IAM user and 100 Cognito users.

Comment: I have Cognito as an Idp to an IdentityPool which we use to get temp IAM creds to auth with API Gateway and S3.